# IntellijIDEA: how to open a project in a tab instead of a new window from OSX cli?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, command-line-interface

I have a very convenient alias `ii='open . -a "IntelliJ IDEA"'` that helps to quickly open projects from cli doing `ii` from a folder. The IDE is configured to open new projects in tabs and it works well when I do it from the **"File → Open Recent"** menu. But when I open using the alias, they always start in separate windows.

Do you know how to open projects from cli into an existing window instead?

Thanks

Comment: this has solved my problem.https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009862859/comments/360003127099

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. MacOS 11-12:  set `Settings | General | Prefer tabs | Always` in your MacOS settings.

MacOS 13-14: `Settings | Desktop & Doc | Windows & Apps | Prefer tabs when opening documents | Always`

2. If you have MacOS 11, use this IDE setting: `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Open project in | Current window`
3. If you have MacOS 12, use this IDE setting: `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Open project in | New window`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow, it looks like `Settings | General | Prefer tabs | Always` in MacOS settings did the trick! Today I learned, thank you, Nadia!

Comment: I have just tried both, but still same problem.

Comment: @olgunyldz, what Idea version and OS do you use?

Comment: Actually, I have selected the "never" and it works

Answer (score 4):

If you have MacOS 13:

1. use this System Setting: Desktop & Dock | Windows && Apps | Prefer tabs when opening documents | Always
2. use this IDE setting: Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Open project in | New window